# php contact form decision making

Tags: php, forms

I am checking to see if fields in a contact form are blank and this works:

```
/*  Check all fields filled in  */          
if( !$name  or !$email or !$comment){
header("Location: error blank field.html");
exit;
}
```

but this does not:

```
/*  Check all fields filled in  */          
if( ($name=null ) or ($email=null) or ($comment=null)){
header("Location: error blank field.html");
exit;
}
```

What am I getting wrong in the second case ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong operator You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`:

```
if( ($name==null ) or ($email==null) or ($comment==null)){
```

FYI, when checking for null values can use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) :

```
if( is_null($name) or is_null($email) or is_null($comment)){
```

You can also use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as `null` is considered an empty value.

```
if( empty($name) or empty($email) or empty($comment)){
```